# Can not see the plots using autoviz in spyder, although the code is running sucessfully

Tags: python, dataframe, plot, visualization, spyder

This is the results i am getting but cant see the plots-

```
Shape of your Data Set loaded: (96, 14)

Classifying variables in data set...
    Number of Numeric Columns =  14
    Number of Integer-Categorical Columns =  0
    Number of String-Categorical Columns =  0
    Number of Factor-Categorical Columns =  0
    Number of String-Boolean Columns =  0
    Number of Numeric-Boolean Columns =  0
    Number of Discrete String Columns =  0
    Number of NLP String Columns =  0
    Number of Date Time Columns =  0
    Number of ID Columns =  0
    Number of Columns to Delete =  0
    14 Predictors classified...
        No variables removed since no ID or low-information variables found in data set
Number of All Scatter Plots = 105
No categorical or numeric vars in data set. Hence no bar charts.
All Plots done
Time to run AutoViz = 4 seconds 

 ###################### AUTO VISUALIZATION Completed ########################
```

I want to see the plots in spyder.

code i am using ---

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from autoviz.AutoViz_Class import AutoViz_Class

AV = AutoViz_Class()


path = r'filename.csv'
ladakhtemp = pd.read_csv(r'ladakhtemp.csv')


filename = "filename.csv"
sep = ","
dft = AV.AutoViz(
    filename,
    sep=",",
    depVar="",
    dfte=None,
    header=0,
    verbose=0,
    lowess=False,
    chart_format="svg",
    max_rows_analyzed=150000,
    max_cols_analyzed=30,
)
```

As it can be seen the code is getting executed successfully but i cant see the results.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem it worked for me when I used this piece of code:

```
%matplotlib inline
```